# getElementsByClassName returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript. I know there are several posts on this topic, but I couldn't find one that seemed to quite address my problem.

I would like to change properties on elements with classes `mainSlides` and `dot`. But when I try to call those elements using `getElementsByClassName`, it returns undefined.

```
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mainSlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
```

When I inserted a breakpoint at `var dots = document ...` slides is undefined. Then I get an error at `slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";`

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

The HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="mainSlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="images/mainSlide1.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
```

and

```
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>
```

I'm not sure if my problem is in setting classes or using `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: If `slides` was undefined then you would get an error trying to read `slideIndex-1` of undefined and not `style` of undefined.

Comment: It seems `slides.length` is `0`, and `slideIndex-1 === -1`. Or maybe `n === 1` and `slideIndex` is not set.

Comment: Just a quick note, you may run into problems with your code for removing the "active" class. You should consider using `dots[i].classList.remove("active")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some logic problems:

- If `n > slides.length` and `n >= 1`, then `slideIndex = 1`

  - If `slides.length >= 1`
    OK, then you can use `slides[slideIndex-1]`
  - If `slides.length === 0`
    Problem, `slides[slideIndex-1]` is `undefined`
- If `1 <= n <= slides.length`, then `slideIndex` is not set
  `slides[slideIndex-1]` is probably a problem.
- If `n < 1`, then `slideIndex = slides.length`

  - If `slides.length >= 1`
    OK, then you can use `slides[slideIndex-1]`
  - If `slides.length === 0`
    Problem, `slides[slideIndex-1]` is `undefined`